# Returning Output Param from SQL Connection

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, parameters

Is this possible or the right way to go about this (if you're not using a stored proc):

```
conn.CommandText = "set @TotalPts = select SUM (pts) from cars where completedDate is not null and customerID = @customerID";
                conn.AddParam("@customerID", customerID);
                conn.AddOutputParam("@TotalPts", SqlDbType.Int);

                return (int)conn.OutputParamValue;
```

I want to get back the sum so I can return it in my C# method.  I'm not sure how to set the output param in the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can instead use ExecuteScalar method as following.

```
conn.CommandText = select SUM (pts) 
                    from cars 
                    where completedDate is not null 
                           and customerID = @customerID";

obj count=cmd.ExecuteScaler();
```

Convert that count to **Integer** using **Convert.ToInt32** function.

Answer (score 0):

Use ExecuteScalar along with "select SUM (pts) from cars where completedDate is not null and customerID = @customerID".

It will give u what's in the first row / column, which is what u want.

Answer (score 0):

> "I'm not sure how to set the output param in the string."

```
select @TotalPts = SUM(pts) from ...
```